# How can I fit this table?

Tags: tables

How I can fit this table??

```
\section*{Tables} \label{sec:tab}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tables}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}

 \begin{landscape}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{rp{5.045em}rrrr|rrrr|rrrr|rrrr}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{4}{p{16.18em}}{\textbf{Healthcare decisions}} & \multicolumn{4}{p{16.18em}}{\textbf{Social decisions}} & \multicolumn{4}{p{16.18em}}{\textbf{Consumption decisions}} & \multicolumn{4}{p{16.18em}}{\textbf{Financial decisions}} \\
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Family elders} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Husband} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Jointly} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Alone} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Family elders} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Husband} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Jointly} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Alone} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Family elders} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Husband} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Jointly} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Alone} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Family elders} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Husband} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Jointly} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{Alone} \\
        \midrule
        & Overall & 0.11  & 0.33  & 0.45  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.29  & 0.46  & 0.07  & 0.17  & 0.31  & 0.44  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.49  & 0.06 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Age}}} & 15-24 & 0.3   & 0.32  & 0.34  & 0.03  & 0.4   & 0.25  & 0.3   & 0.03  & 0.42  & 0.27  & 0.28  & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.44  & 0.48  & 0.04 \\
        & 25-34 & 0.13  & 0.35  & 0.42  & 0.08  & 0.21  & 0.3   & 0.42  & 0.05  & 0.21  & 0.33  & 0.4   & 0.05  & 0     & 0.45  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
        & 35-49 & 0.03  & 0.32  & 0.51  & 0.12  & 0.05  & 0.28  & 0.55  & 0.09  & 0.05  & 0.32  & 0.52  & 0.09  & 0.01  & 0.38  & 0.51  & 0.08 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Education}}} & None  & 0.1   & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.35  & 0.43  & 0.06  & 0.14  & 0.37  & 0.42  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.45  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
        & Primary & 0.15  & 0.29  & 0.45  & 0.08  & 0.2   & 0.23  & 0.48  & 0.07  & 0.22  & 0.27  & 0.42  & 0.07  & 0     & 0.38  & 0.54  & 0.07 \\
        & Secondary & 0.13  & 0.24  & 0.48  & 0.13  & 0.21  & 0.22  & 0.48  & 0.08  & 0.22  & 0.23  & 0.46  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.35  & 0.54  & 0.08 \\
        & Higher & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.54  & 0.17  & 0.18  & 0.14  & 0.58  & 0.09  & 0.19  & 0.16  & 0.54  & 0.09  & 0     & 0.34  & 0.55  & 0.09 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Spouse Education}}} & None  & 0.09  & 0.38  & 0.44  & 0.08  & 0.13  & 0.35  & 0.43  & 0.07  & 0.13  & 0.37  & 0.41  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.44  & 0.47  & 0.07 \\
        & Primary & 0.13  & 0.36  & 0.41  & 0.08  & 0.18  & 0.27  & 0.46  & 0.07  & 0.18  & 0.32  & 0.42  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.5   & 0.07 \\
        & Secondary & 0.14  & 0.29  & 0.46  & 0.09  & 0.19  & 0.26  & 0.47  & 0.06  & 0.2   & 0.27  & 0.45  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.39  & 0.51  & 0.07 \\
        & Higher & 0.1   & 0.28  & 0.49  & 0.11  & 0.18  & 0.23  & 0.51  & 0.07  & 0.17  & 0.26  & 0.49  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.51  & 0.06 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Place of Residence}}} & Rural & 0.12  & 0.38  & 0.42  & 0.06  & 0.17  & 0.33  & 0.43  & 0.05  & 0.17  & 0.36  & 0.41  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.44  & 0.48  & 0.05 \\
        & Urban & 0.1   & 0.25  & 0.5   & 0.14  & 0.16  & 0.21  & 0.52  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.24  & 0.49  & 0.09  & 0     & 0.36  & 0.52  & 0.1 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Family Structure}}} & Joint & 0.34  & 0.28  & 0.32  & 0.05  & 0.48  & 0.2   & 0.26  & 0.04  & 0.49  & 0.21  & 0.25  & 0.03  & 0.02  & 0.48  & 0.44  & 0.05 \\
        & Nuclear & 0.02  & 0.35  & 0.5   & 0.1   & 0.04  & 0.32  & 0.54  & 0.08  & 0.04  & 0.35  & 0.51  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.51  & 0.07 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Women Employed}}} & No    & 0.13  & 0.34  & 0.43  & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.29  & 0.44  & 0.06  & 0.2   & 0.32  & 0.41  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.43  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
        & Yes   & 0.06  & 0.32  & 0.49  & 0.11  & 0.1   & 0.27  & 0.52  & 0.08  & 0.09  & 0.31  & 0.51  & 0.07  & 0     & 0.36  & 0.54  & 0.07 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Economic Status}}} & Poorest & 0.08  & 0.48  & 0.36  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.44  & 0.36  & 0.05  & 0.12  & 0.49  & 0.34  & 0.03  & 0.01  & 0.56  & 0.38  & 0.03 \\
        & Poorer & 0.1   & 0.36  & 0.46  & 0.06  & 0.14  & 0.32  & 0.46  & 0.05  & 0.15  & 0.34  & 0.44  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.52  & 0.05 \\
        & Middle & 0.13  & 0.32  & 0.45  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.28  & 0.46  & 0.07  & 0.18  & 0.29  & 0.44  & 0.07  & 0.01  & 0.37  & 0.53  & 0.08 \\
        & Rich  & 0.15  & 0.25  & 0.47  & 0.11  & 0.2   & 0.22  & 0.49  & 0.07  & 0.21  & 0.24  & 0.45  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.38  & 0.51  & 0.09 \\
        & Richest & 0.1   & 0.24  & 0.5   & 0.14  & 0.18  & 0.18  & 0.53  & 0.09  & 0.19  & 0.21  & 0.5   & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.35  & 0.54  & 0.08 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{\textbf{Region}}} & Islamabad & 0.05  & 0.32  & 0.47  & 0.14  & 0.12  & 0.21  & 0.55  & 0.09  & 0.12  & 0.24  & 0.54  & 0.08  & 0     & 0.38  & 0.52  & 0.08 \\
        & Punjab & 0.11  & 0.26  & 0.51  & 0.11  & 0.16  & 0.21  & 0.54  & 0.07  & 0.16  & 0.23  & 0.52  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.31  & 0.58  & 0.08 \\
        & Sindh & 0.09  & 0.37  & 0.43  & 0.09  & 0.16  & 0.33  & 0.41  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.39  & 0.37  & 0.06  & 0     & 0.5   & 0.43  & 0.05 \\
        & KPK   & 0.18  & 0.45  & 0.3   & 0.05  & 0.23  & 0.4   & 0.31  & 0.04  & 0.25  & 0.4   & 0.3   & 0.04  & 0.02  & 0.55  & 0.37  & 0.04 \\
        & Gilgit & 0.1   & 0.51  & 0.31  & 0.07  & 0.16  & 0.4   & 0.36  & 0.07  & 0.2   & 0.48  & 0.3   & 0.01  & 0.1   & 0.66  & 0.22  & 0.01 \\
        & Balochistan & 0.08  & 0.66  & 0.23  & 0.01  & 0.12  & 0.63  & 0.21  & 0.02  & 0.12  & 0.66  & 0.2   & 0.01  & 0     & 0.74  & 0.23  & 0.01 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{adjustbox} 
\end{landscape}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you search on this site you'll find several examples of too wide/big tables and how to make them fit

Comment: Your table is most likely much too large to fit onto a single page while keeping the font size readable. I would suggest to split the table at least in half. Some other general remarks: Avoid using vertical lines in combination with `booktabs`as they get disrupted by the horizontal rules. In order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal delimiter, you might consider using `S` columns from  the `siunitx` package.

Comment: please activate this question. op prepare code fragment  with bunch of errors, given link doesn't  cover all specific op problems and he is novice. for many novice  we are many time less strict. and last at not a least, i prepare answer which (i hope so) will help him learn how to set tables

Comment: @Zarko then vote to reopen it. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- i don't know, if my solution can help you. you not provide complete but small document from which we can extract information about pages layout of your document
- your table has many errors and code clutter. they are now removed
- use of `multicolumn{1}{p{...}}{...}` for column headers overwrite tables's column definitions. this is removed now
- since your table is huge, i add the package `geometry` and limit table width to `linewidth` with `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{...}`
- to make columns narrower for their headers i use abbreviations with explanation of their meanings in table notes. this is done with use of the package `threeparttable`
- space between columns is determined by `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`
- for columns with numbers is used the `S` column type from package `siunitx`
- text in the first column is in `multirow` cells. by this the column width is reduced

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables}
\label{sec:tab}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tables}
\lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{sidewaystable}
 \begin{threeparttable}[htb]
    \caption{Add caption}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\sisetup{table-format=1.2}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    >{\bfseries\raggedright}p{4.5em}
                                            r
                                      *{16}{S}
                            }
    \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Healthcare\\ decisions}}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Social\\ decisions}}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Consumption\\ decisions}}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Financial\\ decisions}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}\cmidrule{15-18}
    &   & {FE\tnote{a}} & {H\tnote{b}}  & {J\tnote{c}}  & {A\tnote{d}}
    %
        & {FE\tnote{a}} & {H\tnote{b}}  & {J\tnote{c}}  & {A\tnote{d}}
    %
        & {FE\tnote{a}} & {H\tnote{b}}  & {J\tnote{c}}  & {A\tnote{d}}
    %
        & {FE\tnote{a}} & {H\tnote{b}}  & {J\tnote{c}}  & {A\tnote{d}}                  \\
    \midrule
& Overall
    & 0.11  & 0.33  & 0.45  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.29  & 0.46  & 0.07
    & 0.17  & 0.31  & 0.44  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.49  & 0.06 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Age}
& 15-24
    & 0.3   & 0.32  & 0.34  & 0.03  & 0.4   & 0.25  & 0.3   & 0.03
    & 0.42  & 0.27  & 0.28  & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.44  & 0.48  & 0.04 \\
& 25-34
    & 0.13  & 0.35  & 0.42  & 0.08  & 0.21  & 0.3   & 0.42  & 0.05
    & 0.21  & 0.33  & 0.4   & 0.05  & 0     & 0.45  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
& 35-49
    & 0.03  & 0.32  & 0.51  & 0.12  & 0.05  & 0.28  & 0.55  & 0.09
    & 0.05  & 0.32  & 0.52  & 0.09  & 0.01  & 0.38  & 0.51  & 0.08 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{4}{=}{Education}
& None
    & 0.1   & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.35  & 0.43  & 0.06
    & 0.14  & 0.37  & 0.42  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.45  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
& Primary
    & 0.15  & 0.29  & 0.45  & 0.08  & 0.2   & 0.23  & 0.48  & 0.07
    & 0.22  & 0.27  & 0.42  & 0.07  & 0     & 0.38  & 0.54  & 0.07 \\
& Secondary
    & 0.13  & 0.24  & 0.48  & 0.13  & 0.21  & 0.22  & 0.48  & 0.08
    & 0.22  & 0.23  & 0.46  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.35  & 0.54  & 0.08 \\
& Higher
    & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.54  & 0.17  & 0.18  & 0.14  & 0.58  & 0.09
    & 0.19  & 0.16  & 0.54  & 0.09  & 0     & 0.34  & 0.55  & 0.09 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{4}{=}{Spouse Education}
& None
    & 0.09  & 0.38  & 0.44  & 0.08  & 0.13  & 0.35  & 0.43  & 0.07
    & 0.13  & 0.37  & 0.41  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.44  & 0.47  & 0.07 \\
& Primary
    & 0.13  & 0.36  & 0.41  & 0.08  & 0.18  & 0.27  & 0.46  & 0.07
    & 0.18  & 0.32  & 0.42  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.5   & 0.07 \\
& Secondary
    & 0.14  & 0.29  & 0.46  & 0.09  & 0.19  & 0.26  & 0.47  & 0.06
    & 0.2   & 0.27  & 0.45  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.39  & 0.51  & 0.07 \\
& Higher
    & 0.1   & 0.28  & 0.49  & 0.11  & 0.18  & 0.23  & 0.51  & 0.07
    & 0.17  & 0.26  & 0.49  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.51  & 0.06 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{Place of Residence}
& Rural
    & 0.12  & 0.38  & 0.42  & 0.06  & 0.17  & 0.33  & 0.43  & 0.05
    & 0.17  & 0.36  & 0.41  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.44  & 0.48  & 0.05 \\
& Urban
    & 0.1   & 0.25  & 0.5   & 0.14  & 0.16  & 0.21  & 0.52  & 0.09
    & 0.17  & 0.24  & 0.49  & 0.09  & 0     & 0.36  & 0.52  & 0.1 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Family Structure}
& Joint
    & 0.34  & 0.28  & 0.32  & 0.05  & 0.48  & 0.2   & 0.26  & 0.04
    & 0.49  & 0.21  & 0.25  & 0.03  & 0.02  & 0.48  & 0.44  & 0.05 \\
& Nuclear
    & 0.02  & 0.35  & 0.5   & 0.1   & 0.04  & 0.32  & 0.54  & 0.08
    & 0.04  & 0.35  & 0.51  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.51  & 0.07 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Women Employed}
& No
    & 0.13  & 0.34  & 0.43  & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.29  & 0.44  & 0.06
    & 0.2   & 0.32  & 0.41  & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.43  & 0.47  & 0.06 \\
& Yes
    & 0.06  & 0.32  & 0.49  & 0.11  & 0.1   & 0.27  & 0.52  & 0.08
    & 0.09  & 0.31  & 0.51  & 0.07  & 0     & 0.36  & 0.54  & 0.07 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Economic Status}
& Poorest
    & 0.08  & 0.48  & 0.36  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.44  & 0.36  & 0.05
    & 0.12  & 0.49  & 0.34  & 0.03  & 0.01  & 0.56  & 0.38  & 0.03 \\
& Poorer
    & 0.1   & 0.36  & 0.46  & 0.06  & 0.14  & 0.32  & 0.46  & 0.05
    & 0.15  & 0.34  & 0.44  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.4   & 0.52  & 0.05 \\
& Middle
    & 0.13  & 0.32  & 0.45  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.28  & 0.46  & 0.07
    & 0.18  & 0.29  & 0.44  & 0.07  & 0.01  & 0.37  & 0.53  & 0.08 \\
& Rich
    & 0.15  & 0.25  & 0.47  & 0.11  & 0.2   & 0.22  & 0.49  & 0.07
    & 0.21  & 0.24  & 0.45  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.38  & 0.51  & 0.09 \\
& Richest
    & 0.1   & 0.24  & 0.5   & 0.14  & 0.18  & 0.18  & 0.53  & 0.09
    & 0.19  & 0.21  & 0.5   & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.35  & 0.54  & 0.08 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Region}
& Islamabad
    & 0.05  & 0.32  & 0.47  & 0.14  & 0.12  & 0.21  & 0.55  & 0.09
    & 0.12  & 0.24  & 0.54  & 0.08  & 0     & 0.38  & 0.52  & 0.08 \\
& Punjab
    & 0.11  & 0.26  & 0.51  & 0.11  & 0.16  & 0.21  & 0.54  & 0.07
    & 0.16  & 0.23  & 0.52  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.31  & 0.58  & 0.08 \\
& Sindh
    & 0.09  & 0.37  & 0.43  & 0.09  & 0.16  & 0.33  & 0.41  & 0.09
    & 0.17  & 0.39  & 0.37  & 0.06  & 0     & 0.5   & 0.43  & 0.05 \\
& KPK
    & 0.18  & 0.45  & 0.3   & 0.05  & 0.23  & 0.4   & 0.31  & 0.04
    & 0.25  & 0.4   & 0.3   & 0.04  & 0.02  & 0.55  & 0.37  & 0.04 \\
& Gilgit
    & 0.1   & 0.51  & 0.31  & 0.07  & 0.16  & 0.4   & 0.36  & 0.07
    & 0.2   & 0.48  & 0.3   & 0.01  & 0.1   & 0.66  & 0.22  & 0.01 \\
& Balochistan
    & 0.08  & 0.66  & 0.23  & 0.01  & 0.12  & 0.63  & 0.21  & 0.02
    & 0.12  & 0.66  & 0.2   & 0.01  & 0     & 0.74  & 0.23  & 0.01 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}%
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
\item[a] Family elders
\item[b] Husband
\item[c] Jointly
\item[d] Alone
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
     \end{sidewaystable}
\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**note:**
for one page table instead `landscape` is better to use the environment `sidewaystable`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have 28 tables and each table has 11 columns and 30 rows in word (Landscape). I tried to use excel to Latex and word to latex software but remain unsuccessful. Please guide me, what can I do for generate my tables code for latex. Thanks in advance. Is there any way on LyX??

Comment: well, you select another answer as the best for you, so i expect that your further work on tables will based on it and not on my answer :-). in this i cant help you, sorry.

Comment: I just new on this page sir and don't know well about this page rules.

Comment: @RashidJaved, in (both) answers you can see, how to write tables in `latex`. you only need to accommodate number of lines. if table is longer than text height, than you had to use the packages`longtable` or `tablex` for table and table set in `landscape` page instead as `sidewaystable`. if you will stuck in this, ask new question (but in it always provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`). it's generally good to read some introduction texts about writing tables as is https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Thank a lot dear Zarko for your help. Can you please tell me "\multirow[t]{5}{=}", in multirow, what the number implies? Secondly, I run your code in my "TexStudio" and get the table but there is a text before and after the table. In fact, in syntax there is no any such kind of text mentioned.

Comment: @RashidJaved, for `\multirow` is the best to read its documentation :-). anyway: `[t]` means that text in the cell will be aligned at top of the cell, `{5}` is the number of lines in neighbor cells which span multi row cell (in your case is equal to number of rows)  and`{=}` means that the column format will be preserved in this cell (`p{4.5em}`),.

Answer (score 3):

One of the golden rules about tables is “avoid repeating information”. In this case, repeating “decisions” four times calls for a dedicated header.

The leftmost column might become titles for sections of the table (`\multicolumn`}, but in this case we need to fill up text for the sideways table; there's no hope to reduce it to fit in standard position.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{This is the caption}\label{label}

\newcommand{\leftcol}[1]{%
  \smash{%
    \itshape
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\small

\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{16}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{}}
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{16}{c@{}}{\bfseries Decisions} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-18}
&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Healthcare}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Social}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Consumption}
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\bfseries Financial} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-14} \cmidrule(l){15-18}
&& {FE} & {H} & {J} & {A}
& {FE} & {H} & {J} & {A}
& {FE} & {H} & {J} & {A}
& {FE} & {H} & {J} & {A} \\
\midrule
& Overall
& 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.45 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.29 & 0.46 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.31 & 0.44 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.41 & 0.49 & 0.06 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Age}
& 15-24 & 0.3  & 0.32 & 0.34 & 0.03 & 0.4  & 0.25 & 0.3  & 0.03 & 0.42 & 0.27 & 0.28 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.44 & 0.48 & 0.04 \\
& 25-34 & 0.13 & 0.35 & 0.42 & 0.08 & 0.21 & 0.3  & 0.42 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.33 & 0.4  & 0.05 & 0   & 0.45 & 0.47 & 0.06 \\
& 35-49 & 0.03 & 0.32 & 0.51 & 0.12 & 0.05 & 0.28 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.32 & 0.52 & 0.09 & 0.01 & 0.38 & 0.51 & 0.08 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Education}
& None & 0.1  & 0.39 & 0.43 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.35 & 0.43 & 0.06 & 0.14 & 0.37 & 0.42 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.45 & 0.47 & 0.06 \\
& Primary & 0.15 & 0.29 & 0.45 & 0.08 & 0.2  & 0.23 & 0.48 & 0.07 & 0.22 & 0.27 & 0.42 & 0.07 & 0   & 0.38 & 0.54 & 0.07 \\
& Secondary & 0.13 & 0.24 & 0.48 & 0.13 & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.48 & 0.08 & 0.22 & 0.23 & 0.46 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.35 & 0.54 & 0.08 \\
& Higher & 0.08 & 0.19 & 0.54 & 0.17 & 0.18 & 0.14 & 0.58 & 0.09 & 0.19 & 0.16 & 0.54 & 0.09 & 0   & 0.34 & 0.55 & 0.09 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Spouse \\ Education}
& None & 0.09 & 0.38 & 0.44 & 0.08 & 0.13 & 0.35 & 0.43 & 0.07 & 0.13 & 0.37 & 0.41 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.44 & 0.47 & 0.07 \\
& Primary & 0.13 & 0.36 & 0.41 & 0.08 & 0.18 & 0.27 & 0.46 & 0.07 & 0.18 & 0.32 & 0.42 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.41 & 0.5  & 0.07 \\
& Secondary & 0.14 & 0.29 & 0.46 & 0.09 & 0.19 & 0.26 & 0.47 & 0.06 & 0.2  & 0.27 & 0.45 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.39 & 0.51 & 0.07 \\
& Higher & 0.1  & 0.28 & 0.49 & 0.11 & 0.18 & 0.23 & 0.51 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.26 & 0.49 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.4  & 0.51 & 0.06 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Place of \\ Residence}
& Rural & 0.12 & 0.38 & 0.42 & 0.06 & 0.17 & 0.33 & 0.43 & 0.05 & 0.17 & 0.36 & 0.41 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.44 & 0.48 & 0.05 \\
& Urban & 0.1  & 0.25 & 0.5  & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.21 & 0.52 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.24 & 0.49 & 0.09 & 0   & 0.36 & 0.52 & 0.1 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Family \\ Structure}
& Joint & 0.34 & 0.28 & 0.32 & 0.05 & 0.48 & 0.2  & 0.26 & 0.04 & 0.49 & 0.21 & 0.25 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.48 & 0.44 & 0.05 \\
& Nuclear & 0.02 & 0.35 & 0.5  & 0.1  & 0.04 & 0.32 & 0.54 & 0.08 & 0.04 & 0.35 & 0.51 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.4  & 0.51 & 0.07 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Women \\ Employed}
& No  & 0.13 & 0.34 & 0.43 & 0.08 & 0.19 & 0.29 & 0.44 & 0.06 & 0.2  & 0.32 & 0.41 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.43 & 0.47 & 0.06 \\
& Yes  & 0.06 & 0.32 & 0.49 & 0.11 & 0.1  & 0.27 & 0.52 & 0.08 & 0.09 & 0.31 & 0.51 & 0.07 & 0   & 0.36 & 0.54 & 0.07 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Economic \\ Status}
& Poorest & 0.08 & 0.48 & 0.36 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.44 & 0.36 & 0.05 & 0.12 & 0.49 & 0.34 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.56 & 0.38 & 0.03 \\
& Poorer & 0.1  & 0.36 & 0.46 & 0.06 & 0.14 & 0.32 & 0.46 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0.34 & 0.44 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.4  & 0.52 & 0.05 \\
& Middle & 0.13 & 0.32 & 0.45 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.28 & 0.46 & 0.07 & 0.18 & 0.29 & 0.44 & 0.07 & 0.01 & 0.37 & 0.53 & 0.08 \\
& Rich & 0.15 & 0.25 & 0.47 & 0.11 & 0.2  & 0.22 & 0.49 & 0.07 & 0.21 & 0.24 & 0.45 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.38 & 0.51 & 0.09 \\
& Richest & 0.1  & 0.24 & 0.5  & 0.14 & 0.18 & 0.18 & 0.53 & 0.09 & 0.19 & 0.21 & 0.5  & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.35 & 0.54 & 0.08 \\
\midrule
\leftcol{Region}
& Islamabad & 0.05 & 0.32 & 0.47 & 0.14 & 0.12 & 0.21 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.54 & 0.08 & 0   & 0.38 & 0.52 & 0.08 \\
& Punjab & 0.11 & 0.26 & 0.51 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.21 & 0.54 & 0.07 & 0.16 & 0.23 & 0.52 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.31 & 0.58 & 0.08 \\
& Sindh & 0.09 & 0.37 & 0.43 & 0.09 & 0.16 & 0.33 & 0.41 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.39 & 0.37 & 0.06 & 0   & 0.5  & 0.43 & 0.05 \\
& KPK  & 0.18 & 0.45 & 0.3  & 0.05 & 0.23 & 0.4  & 0.31 & 0.04 & 0.25 & 0.4  & 0.3  & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.55 & 0.37 & 0.04 \\
& Gilgit & 0.1  & 0.51 & 0.31 & 0.07 & 0.16 & 0.4  & 0.36 & 0.07 & 0.2  & 0.48 & 0.3  & 0.01 & 0.1  & 0.66 & 0.22 & 0.01 \\
& Balochistan & 0.08 & 0.66 & 0.23 & 0.01 & 0.12 & 0.63 & 0.21 & 0.02 & 0.12 & 0.66 & 0.2  & 0.01 & 0   & 0.74 & 0.23 & 0.01 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{18}{@{}l@{}}{FE: family elders; H: husband; J: joint; A: alone}
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “temporary” command is defined to ease input of the entries in the leftmost column.